# What does vim wrap option actually do?

Tags: vim

I tried removing "set wrap" from my vimrc. I also set textwidth to 0. Still it wraps the lines  when it reaches window borders, i.e. no difference. So what does it actually do? I don't notice any difference after disabling it.

Also I like the way textwidth works in the sense that it does not break based on window size. Is there a way to have vim do that, but visually (no real line break chars)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that a hard wrap (i.e. a newline is actually inserted in to the buffer), or the soft (only visible) wrap that `:set wrap` is about?!

Answer (score 3):

to disable any command you should put a `no` in front of the keyword. for example `set nowrap`

Comment: Right. I didn't realize it was active by default. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should definetely learn how to use the built-in help.

From inside Vim, you can type `:help wrap` and it will lead you to a nice description of the option.

It is also possible that when you are doing the test, the option is not active, because it has been disabled by a plugin/filetype/whatever.

If you want to be sure that you option is active, type `:set wrap?`. It will either display :

- `wrap` if option is enabled
- `nowrap`if option is disabled